# number of space between each word

Tags: python, numbers, cpu-word

How can I find a quick way to count the number of spacing between each word in a text?

Each space represents a value,

Example: one space is the letter 'a', two spaces is the letter 'b', etc..

An example with the text

**text :**

```
hello all  the   world
```

one space between hello and all --> 'a', two spaces between all and the --> 'b', ...

**word -->** 'abc'

Comment: `text : "hello all the world" one space between hello and all --> 'a', two spaces between all and the --> 'b', ...` - I don't understand the last part of that example. I can only see one space between each word in the example sentence.

Comment: @birryree If you look at the source, it seems that he typed "hello_all__the___world", but the editor doesn't show the extra spaces.

Comment: @brc - oh I see it now - JBernardo edited it and I guess only code mode works for multi-spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
import string

''.join(map(lambda x: string.lowercase[len(x) - 1], re.findall(r'\s+', 'hello all  the   world')))
# 'abc'
```

Answer (score 3):

For entertainment value -- and because I don't like regular expressions but do like the itertools module -- another way to do this is to know that you can use itertools.groupby to collect objects by like kind:

```
>>> from string import lowercase
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> 
>>> s = 'hello all  the   world'
>>> counts = [(len(list(cpart))) for c,cpart in groupby(s) if c == ' ']
>>> counts
[1, 2, 3]
>>> values = [lowercase[count-1] for count in counts]
>>> values
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> vs = ''.join(values)
>>> vs
'abc'
```

[itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is often very useful.

Comment: Like your answer more than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming i got you right:

```
from string import lowercase

word = lowercase[:text.count(' ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd specify the output format you want, I could make this more specific, but this should put you well on your way to a complete solution.

```
import re

word_re = re.compile('(\W*)(\w+)'):

for match in word_re.finditer(text)
    spaces, word = match.groups()
    print len(spaces), word
```

Note: `\w` stands for "word characters" and \W is the opposite. Depending on your exact problem you may want to make these more specific.

Reference: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax